# Making an array reactive in vue Composition API

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

This seems simple but I could not find an answer. I have a form and all inputs are put in an object. Now the backend requires the form object to be wrapped in an array. So I have this :

```
    <input
       class="input"
       placeholder="Serial #"
       v-model="form.serialNum"
    />
// etc for form
```

and in <script setup>

```
let form = reactive({
  eqpmntType: "",
  make: "",
  modelNum: "",
  // etc
```

So I read docs and understand reactive function is for objects so I tried ref():

```
let form = ref([{
  eqpmntType: "",
  make: "",
  modelNum: "",
  //etc
   }]
```

And unfortunately I lose my reactivity for the form inputs. I know I can wrap the form object in an array after the fact and submit. I was wondering if there is a way to make an array or for that matter an array of objects *reactive*. Thanks for any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I think your initiated `form` is reactive and have no problem to me. Maybe it is how you use it.

For example, if you want to alter the value of `modelNum` within `form`, since it is an Array type now, make sure you did this:

```
form.value[0].modelNum = 123
```

And in the `input` element, the v-model should be `v-model="form[0].modelNum"` also because of type Array.

Althogh I don't see why the backend requires you to pass Array-type params since it seems `form` only contains 1 Object within the array. Normally, in below case, Array-type params will be adopted:

```
const form = ref([
  {
    eqpmntType: "1",
    make: "1",
    modelNum: "1"
  },
  {
    eqpmntType: "2",
    make: "2",
    modelNum: "2"
  },
  {
    eqpmntType: "3",
    make: "3",
    modelNum: "3"
  },
])
```

In this case, your `input` must be more than one so that each v-model of one `input` will bind each `modelNum` respectively. So if this answer doesn't solve your problem, I would like you to display more code and details.